# Sequential custom type traits behaving as one

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

I'm trying to define custom type traits (to which i'm relatively new), that check if given type supports a specific operation. If i just have one type trait it works as intended, but if i put two type traits sequentially both of them behave as one (when i use second one, it returns same result as the first one).
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Code sample:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_comparable_by_equal_to
    : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_comparable_by_equal_to<T, typename std::enable_if<true,
    decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>(), (void)0)>::type>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_comparable_by_not_equal_to
    : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_comparable_by_not_equal_to<T, typename std::enable_if<true,
    decltype(std::declval<T>() != std::declval<T>(), (void)0)>::type>
    : std::true_type {};

class mClass {
public:
    bool operator== (const mClass& obj) {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    printf("%s: %d\n", "is_comparable_by_equal_to",
        is_comparable_by_equal_to<mClass>::value);
    printf("%s: %d\n", "is_comparable_by_not_equal_to",
        is_comparable_by_not_equal_to<mClass>::value);
}
```

Resulting output:

> is_comparable_by_equal_to: 1
>   is_comparable_by_not_equal_to: 1

Intended result output:

> is_comparable_by_equal_to: 1
>   is_comparable_by_not_equal_to: 0

Question is why and how to solve the problem? Also i'm open for improvements how to define such custom type traits.

Comment: If I compile your code with `g++ -std=c++11 traits.cpp` (or c++14), I get the intended result.

Comment: VS compiler `19.10.24903.0` gives the intended result, try here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: intended result with clang++ (3.5) and g++ (4.9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the code with g++ -std=c++11 and it worked as intended.

As it turned out, problem was in Visual Studio 2015 compiler version (VS2015 update 2), when I updated to latest version (update 3) it worked as intended.